# Spyder IDE plugins installation (spyder-unittest)

Tags: python, plugins, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to install a plugin for the Spyder ide called **spyder-unittest** (description [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-unittest)).

I am using:

MacOS X Version 10.14.6

Anaconda Navigator 1.9.7

Spyder 3.3.6

Python 3.7

After a first attempt using the command

`conda install -c spyder-ide spyder-unittest`

the plugin did not work (i.e. the additional command  **Run unit tests** was not available under the **Run** menu).

I also tried, without success:

`conda install -c conda-forge spyder-unittest`

I then uninstalled and installed once again Anaconda navigator, and tried `conda install -c spyder-ide spyder-unittest`. This time, I got a very lengthy output, indicating conflicts (please see image):

[image]

Now, I do not know what to do. Could someone please offer any help?

I also tried to install after going, through the Terminal, to the directory where I thought the Spyder plugins were installed. Same output as above.

Thank you very much in advance.

Cheers,
Orlando

Answer (score 2):

I managed to install **spyder-unittest** without any errors on my computer.
I suggest creating a new environment to avoid any conflicts with other packages when installing.

First create a new environment using:

`conda create --name env python=3.7`

After creating the environment, activate it using `conda activate env`

Then install **spyder-unittest** using `conda install -c conda-forge spyder-unittest`

Comment: Thank you very much. I am sorry I am not completely aware of how different environments work. Does this mean I have two different "versions" of Conda running in parallel? how does this affect the execution of my scripts and the way I use my Pyhion packages? is there a place where I can find information about this? Finally, is this a known bug that they are gonna solve, or do I have to find a workaround myself? Thank you very much again and sorry for all the questions, I am a newbie with these things...

Comment: Each environment is its own separate thing. They are useful when dealing with different projects or versions of packages without affecting another. You can read some more about it here: https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/ 
I do not know if this is a known bug since I have not used or searched up anything about spyder-unittest.

Comment: thank you very much Jason, I will have a look at it and try, your help was really useful. I will come back and update about how I solved the problem. Cheers, Orlando